# Duplicate IPs for nodes causing backup issues

Tags: sql-server, dns, round-robin, windows-clustering

We have a four node cluster (SQL Server 2014 on Windows 12) and we recently setup heart beat network on the nodes following a best practices source after experiencing some cluster instability issues. Ever since a couple of secondary nodes are returning multiple IPs in the DNS. We have removed the entries from the DNS server for both the nodes multiple times but the IPs of the heartbeat network (the IPs are supposed to be non-routable) keep popping ultimately returning two IPs for the same node and this is causing issues with our backups. I have checked the settings on all four nodes and they are the same in the network adapter properties. What am I doing wrong?

PS:  addition I have also changed some settings in the TCP/IPv4 properties such as removing the DNS server addresses and unchecking the 'register this connection's address in DNS'

Comment: This isn't really a programming question. I think you will get better answers at https://serverfault.com

Comment: Also, because the links to those images might break in the future, it's best for your question not to depend on them. Can you edit your question to describe the settings you tried in the text?

Comment: Possibly better suited to dba.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Thanks! Will post in dba.stackexchange.com or serverfault.com